# Captcha Implementation in Angular and Spring Based web application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, recaptcha, captcha

How I can implement captcha in an angular application having Java - spring boot as a backend. I can't use Google's reCaptcha library as the server hosting the application doesn't have Internet access.

Currently, I'm passing a captcha numeric code from Java backend to frontend and matching it from the user entered code, but in testing, it is found as an insecure approach as captcha sent from the backend is textual form.

Comment: Without the backend to verify the captcha - that is only on the client side, the captcha would be very easy to side-step and basically ignore. Such captcha would not protect you from bots in anyway.

How is it possible, that your backend that serves your application doesn't have access to the internet? How is the web application served then?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following dependency to your pom.xml

   cn.apiclub.tool
        simplecaptcha
        1.2.2
2. create a module in spring boot and add the following classes:

   package com.java.captcha;
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;
   import cn.apiclub.captcha.Captcha;

   ```
   public class CaptchaDetails implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -4326389569050611057L;
       private final String answer;
       private final Captcha captcha;

       public CaptchaDetails(HttpServletRequest request){
           this.answer=request.getParameter("captcha");
           this.captcha=(Captcha) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, "captcha");
       }

       public String getAnswer() {
           return answer;
       }

       public Captcha getCaptcha() {
           return captcha;
       }
   }
   ```

---

```
package com.java.captcha;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

import cn.apiclub.captcha.Captcha;
import cn.apiclub.captcha.backgrounds.BackgroundProducer;
import cn.apiclub.captcha.backgrounds.TransparentBackgroundProducer;
import cn.apiclub.captcha.noise.CurvedLineNoiseProducer;
import cn.apiclub.captcha.noise.NoiseProducer;
import cn.apiclub.captcha.text.producer.DefaultTextProducer;
import cn.apiclub.captcha.text.producer.TextProducer;
import cn.apiclub.captcha.text.renderer.DefaultWordRenderer;
import cn.apiclub.captcha.text.renderer.WordRenderer;

public class CaptchaGenerator implements InitializingBean {
    
    private BackgroundProducer backgroundProducer==new TransparentBackgroundProducer();
    private TextProducer textProducer=new DefaultTextProducer();
    private WordRenderer wordRenderer=new DefaultWordRenderer();
    private NoiseProducer noiseProducer=new CurvedLineNoiseProducer();
    
    public Captcha createCaptcha(int width, int height){
        return new Captcha.Builder(width, height)
                .addBackground(backgroundProducer)
                .addText(textProducer,wordRenderer)
                .addNoise(noiseProducer).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if(this.backgroundProducer==null){
            this.backgroundProducer=new TransparentBackgroundProducer();
        }
        if(this.textProducer==null){
            this.textProducer=new DefaultTextProducer();
        }
        if(this.wordRenderer==null){
            this.wordRenderer= new DefaultWordRenderer();
        }
        if(this.noiseProducer==null){
            this.noiseProducer=new CurvedLineNoiseProducer();
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
package com.java.captcha;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import cn.apiclub.captcha.Captcha;

public abstract class CaptchaUtils {
    public static String encodeBase64(Captcha captcha){
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(captcha.getImage(), "png", outputStream);
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(outputStream.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Once this is done you go to you dataprovider class and write code as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.java.captcha.CaptchaGenerator;
import com.java.captcha.CaptchaUtils;

import cn.apiclub.captcha.Captcha;
import oracle.jdbc.logging.annotations.Logging;

public class XYZDataprovider{
    public Map<String, ?> getData(String dpMethod, HttpSession session, Map<?,?>allRequestParams, Object masterData,  
    Logging logging){
    Map<String, Object>responseHashMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    Map<String,Object>dataHashMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    if(dpMethod.equals("getCaptchaDet")){
    try {
                    CaptchaGenerator captchaGenerator = new CaptchaGenerator();
                    Captcha captcha = captchaGenerator.createCaptcha(200, 50);
                    dataHashMap.put("captchaAns", captcha.getAnswer());
                    dataHashMap.put("captchaCode", CaptchaUtils.encodeBase64(captcha));
                    responseHashMap.put("responseData", dataHashMap);
                    responseHashMap.put(SUCCESS, true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();      
                }
    }
 }
}
```